# Sphinx Documentation WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

After generating html file by make html command, documention is not generated properly. I followed all the steps of sphnix documentation. Where did it go wrong?

**My project directory:**

```
|--web_app
      |--accounts
        |--__pycache__
        |--migrations
        |--__init__.py
        |--admin.py
        |--app.py
        |--models.py
        |--test.py
        |--urls.py
        |--views.py
      |--docs
        |--_build
        |--_static
        |--_templates
        |--conf.py
        |--index.rst
        |--Make.bat
        |--Makefile
        |--models.rst
        |--accounts.migrations.rst
        |--accounts.rst
      |--venv
      |--manage.py
```

**Conf.py file:**

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'sphinx.ext.doctest',
              'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
              'sphinx.ext.todo',
              'sphinx.ext.coverage',
              'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
              'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
              'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
              'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
              'sphinx.ext.napoleon'

]

html_theme = 'alabaster'


html_static_path = ['_static']
```

**index.rst**

```
Welcome to Rest's documentation!
=======================================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

**modules.rst**

```
accounts
========

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   accounts
```

**Error Message:**

WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'models' from module 'accounts'; the following exception was raised:

Comment: This looks similar to many other questions (for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/71652709/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71652709/407651), but I don't see anything obviously wrong. `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))` looks right.

Comment: Is this anything related to the virtual environement or any other dependencies?

Comment: I don't know. It is hard to help without a [mcve].

Comment: After adding few lines in `conf.py` file, It works perfectly.

`import django
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'real_estate.settings'
django.setup()`