# WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module when trying to generate python documentation with sphinx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have reviewed the sphinx documentation to generate the python documentation. When I generate the documentation in html format using the .rst files that do not reference any python source code, the documentation is generated correctly.

In my configuration I work with the following files: conf.py, index.rst, tutorial.rst, project.rst and pkg_app.rst

I attach the content of each of them:

conf.py:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))

# -- General configuration ------------------------------------------------


# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

project = 'hmed'
copyright = '2023, Ramiro Jativa'
author = 'Ramiro Jativa'
release = '1.0.41'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']



# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

index.rst:

```
.. hmed documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Thu Apr 27 17:53:25 2023.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to hmed's documentation!
================================

Requirements for production:

MySQL
Python
Flask
PyPi Libraries

Requirements for development:

sqlite3
Python
Flask
PyPi Libraries 

Project structure:

project_name/pkg_app (include the source code distributed in various modules. And includes the __init__.py file)
project_name/sphinx_documentation (is the folder where the sphinx documentation is generated)

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   tutorial
   project
   pkg_app

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

tutorial.rst:

```
Tutorial
========

Modules
-------

Module 1: Tutorial for module 1.

This is the content for tutorial 1.

Module 2: Tutorial for module 2.

This is the content for tutorial 2.
```

project.rst:

```
Project Documentation
=====================

Achieved goals
--------------

Goal 1: This is the description of goal 1.

This is the detail of what was done to achieve goal 1.

Goal 2: This is the description of goal 2.

This is the detail of what was done to achieve goal 2.

Learned lessons
---------------

This paragraph describes what was learned in the project.
```

pkg_app.rst:

```
Source code documentation
=========================

The pkg_app folder includes the __init__.py, models.py, forms.py, and routes.py files
```

Using the indicated configuration, I proceed to execute the make html command and the documentation is generated by sphinx correctly.

Next I include the log of the execution of the make html command:

```
(venv_hmed) $ make clean
Removing everything under '_build'...
(venv_hmed) $ make html
Running Sphinx v5.3.0
making output directory... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 4 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 4 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] tutorial                                                                                           
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] tutorial                                                                                            
generating indices... genindex done
writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

As a result, the documentation is obtained in html format as indicated below:

[image]

Up to this point everything works correctly.

***To generate the documentation of the files with the .py extension that are inside the pkg_app directory structure, I modify the content of the pkg_app.rst file with the following content:***

pkg_app.rst:

```
Source code documentation
=========================

The pkg_app folder includes the __init__.py, models.py, forms.py, and routes.py files

Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: pkg_app
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

When the make html command is entered to generate the documentation in sphinx, the following warning message is displayed:

```
(venv_hmed) $ make clean
Removing everything under '_build'...
(venv_hmed) $ make html
Running Sphinx v5.3.0
making output directory... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 4 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 4 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] tutorial                                                                                           
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'pkg_app'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'pkg_app'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] tutorial                                                                                            
generating indices... genindex done
writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.

The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

QUESTION:

what is the correct configuration of the pkg_app.rst file so that it can generate the python documentation of all the modules inside the pkg_app package?

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says it cannot import your Python package. You have `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))`, which is the current directory containing the documentation. Try `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))`.

Comment: Looks similar to other existing questions, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763542/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50230797/407651.