# How to get correct path for Sphinx autodoc with os.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc

I just built Sphinx for the first time and generated all of the skeleton files.  Next I want to add another path with Python files for autodoc to analyze.  `sphinx.ext.autodoc` is in conf.py as an extension.

My Sphinx install is in: `/home/mbcn/Software_Projects/Sphinx`.
The other path I want to include is `/home/mbcn/Software_Projects/Python_Projects/Svnx`

I edited `conf.py` and uncommented these lines:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

Then I ran make html again.  Nothing changed; no new files were analyzed.  So I tried:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/mbcn/Software_Projects/Python_Projects/Svnx/'))
```

Still nothing changed.  So I tried:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('os.path.realpath('/home/mbcn/Software_Projects/Python_Projects/Svnx/’)'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Your value for `abspath` should be your package's relative path from `conf.py`. It's not clear from the information provided where your `conf.py` for this project is on your system. See example at https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#example-of-configuration-file

Comment: Looks similar to many other questions, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763542/407651 and  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50230797/407651.