# Generating sphinx documentation for ROS package - No module named '..'

Tags: python, python-sphinx, ros, autodoc

I am trying to generate sphinx docs for some python modules in a ROS package, but I encountered an issue where the autodoc does not find some of the imports. The imports in question are generated from [action definitions](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib):

```
from dialogflow_actions.msg import (
    TurnToHumanAction,
    TurnToHumanFeedback,
    TurnToHumanResult,
)
```

I get an error saying that the package is not found:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'turn_to_human_action_client' from module u'dialogflow_actions.clients'; the following exception was raised:
No module named msg
```

I tried adding the path to the generated modules to conf.py:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/wstyczen/tiago_public_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dialogflow_actions'))
```

and adding an .rst for those generated modules, but it does not help - still an error that the module is not found.

Has anyone had a similar issue? I couldn't find a solution anywhere and right now it does not generate the documentation for any of the files with similar imports. Thanks!

Comment: Many similar questions have been asked before, For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53668052/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57763542/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50230797/407651

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sphinx cannot find my python files. Says 'no module named ...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668052/sphinx-cannot-find-my-python-files-says-no-module-named)